# How to pre-process and extract the Nvidia hand Gesture dataset?

Tags: dataset, video-processing, unzip, cat, 7zip

There are 31 files named:

```
                          nvGesture_v1.7z.001
                         to nvGesture_v1.7z.031
```

I am looking to extract these files to video format. Since these files are zipped in .7z format. I tried using

```
                          cat nvGesture_v1.7z.0?? | 7za x
```

or

```
                          cat nvGesture_v1.7z.0?? | 7za e
```

but in both cases I get error:

```
                            Error:
                            Incorrect command line
```

Comment: I'm doing that as well. `7z e nvGesture_v1.7z.001` is a good start. It will unzip the files, but in a not-so-smart way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, 2 min after I posted the comment on the original questions, I think I got what you need:

`7z x nvGesture_v1.7z.001`

It will unzip the videos in the original folder structure:
    Video_data
        class_01
            subject1_r0
(etc)